# Primefaces editor in a dialog doesn't works

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, editor

I have a dialog to insert some fields, one of those is a p:editor which is displayed like it is disabled while it is not. A strange "true" string is displayed into the editor body.
The code:

```
<p:dialog id="insertPanel" header="Inserisci" widgetVar="dlg1" appendToBody="true" modal="true">
  <h:form id="insertForm">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
      <h:outputLabel value="Nome: " for="name" />
      <p:inputText id="name" value="#{controller.name}" />
      <h:outputLabel value="Oggetto: " for="subject" />
      <p:inputText id="subject" value="#{controller.subject}" />
      <h:outputLabel value="Visibilità: " for="visibility" />
      <p:inputText id="visibility" value="#{controller.visibility}" />
      <h:outputLabel value="Testo: " for="text" />
      <p:editor id="text" value="#{controller.text}" width="600"/>
      <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton actionListener="#{controller.insert}" value="Inserisci" />
      </f:facet>
    </h:panelGrid>
  </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

An image of the dialog that shows the problem:

[image: Editor in dialog problem]

As you can see the editor is like disabled and shows "true" into its body.

Comment: If it can help, I notice that if I press Insert button without insert other fields the form return with validation error, and only then the editor starts to work! I can't understand why!

Comment: Are you placing the `<p:dialog>` inside any other PrimeFaces components like `<p:layout>`?

Comment: Yes, it is inside a `<p:layout>`, but there is `appendToBody="true"`, it shouldn't fix almost anything?

Comment: Here we have a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743084/primefaces-editor-displays-true-when-re-rendered/30606959#30606959 but in this case is when the editor is re-rendered

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this issue.
I've just put `update=":insertForm"` into the commandButton that opens the dialog and it works.

```
<p:commandButton id="insertButton" value="Inserisci" oncomplete="dlg1.show();" update=":insertForm" />
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing the solution. did you get to know why it works only if you update the form ??

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `showEffect="fade"` to dialog component.

Comment: Please explain in detail what the probable cause is and why you think that this is the solution. This answer is otherwise unhelpful/useless and could better be posted as a comment.

Comment: I can't add comments yet because of low reputation :(

I got the same problem before and solved it by checking the following answer on primefaces forum   http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8993&start=10[link]

Comment: This is work for me. Very strange. Did you find out the reason ?

Comment: I had the same problem like that in the question with effect slide. When I delete effect or change it to fade effect it works. It is strange.

Comment: Strangely enough this worked for me, I was using the blind effect and it was not working even updating the component on show, changed to fade effect and it worked.