# post value from interface to db, and find out why <p:editor> is disabled

Tags: java, jsf, methods, primefaces

I'm new to JSF and primefaces, and I'm trying to implement a function to open a popup and create content in there and save it.

I have a storyboard must be able to contain several scenes.
I created the db to work this way:
[image]

So, a Project can have several Units. Each unit has 1 storyboard("Roteiros") and each storyboard can have several scenes ("Slides") associated.

I'm trying to understand how to create a function to add these slides for the scenes in the application I'm working on.

I have a managedbean called cadRoteiro, where I can set methods to use in this functionality.

**Interface Issue:**

I have a popup for storyboard information (a list of scenes). I'm trying to create a button there to add scenes. The user clicks on this button and opens a popup with a  having two inputs (title, description). I'm having problems to create this button:

```
    <p:commandButton id="addScene" value="#{msg.add}" style="float:right;"
        actionListener="#{cadRoteiro.novoSlide()}"
        oncomplete="dialogTarefa.show()"
        update=":tabUnidadeSlideTarefa:dlgTarefa,
                :tabUnidadeSlideTarefa:formCadastroTarefas">
    </p:commandButton>
```

Could you help me to understand how should be this `novoSlide()` method?

```
public void novoSlide() {
    this.slide = new Slide();
    changingSlide = false;
    disabledSlide = true;
}
```

Also, the button to add scene I mentioned above opens the popup, but the editor (whose content I want to be the description of a new scene) is coming disabled. (the solution posted here: [Primefaces editor in a dialog doesn't works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982922/primefaces-editor-in-a-dialog-doesnt-works) **doesn't work** for me (the problem must be before that).

I know it's a lot of information, but I'm new to this and I really need some help, basically for two things: understand how could I create a method to get values from interface posted there, and to understand why  is not being updated when the second popup is being opened.

**Managed Bean code (cadRoteiro):** http://pastebin.com/sGBws74h

**Popup where form is:** http://pastebin.com/9A2ZZtt7

Comment: Please provide the code where your popup is (in the same `<h:form>` of this `<p:commandButton>` or outside) and the respective managed bean code in order to have a better understanding of your problem. Remember that this is technical stuff and we prefer to analyse this in technical level more than in end user terms.

Comment: sure.. I'll post it in pastebin.. just a second..

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza just did!