# primefaces editor displays true when re-rendered

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have an editor in my project:

```
<p:editor id="content" value="#{myBean.content}" width="1000" height="400"/>
<h:message for="content" errorClass="invalid"/>
```

and when I refresh my form using ajax in a commandLink:

```
<p:commandLink styleClass="btn" action="#{myBean.save()}" value="Save">
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form" />
</p:commandLink>
```

the content of the p:edit element switches to "true" and I can't modify it anymore. This only happens when I sue firefox, with chrome it works normally. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Post your backend code too. Anyway: f:ajax is inappropriate here, primefaces uses p:ajax. But it's built into the commandLink, so use it this way: <p:commandLink styleClass="btn" action="#{myBean.save()}" value="Save" update="@form" />. render=update, execute=process, but process is not needed since the @form is the default for commandLink.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why but if you change f:ajax for p:ajax like this:

```
<p:commandLink styleClass="btn" action="#{myBean.save()}" value="Save">
    <p:ajax process="@form" update="@form" />
</p:commandLink>
```

everything works fine.

Comment: This is a similar issue https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6580